# Categories List with number of products associated

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I implemented the following query that list all categories and gives the number of products associated with each of them.

```
SELECT tm.term_id, tm.name, count(tm.name) as total_products
FROM mg_term_taxonomy tx
LEFT JOIN mg_terms tm
ON tx.term_id=tm.term_id
LEFT JOIN mg_term_relationships tr
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tx.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tx.taxonomy='product_cat'
GROUP BY tm.term_id
```

The problem is on categories that have any associated product. In this case, total_products count it as 1 instead of 0. 
The question is how to get 0 in total_products if tr.object_id is NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the field that you want counted:

```
SELECT tm.term_id, tm.name, count(tr.object_id) as total_products
. . .
```

Comment: Yesss, it is. Thanks Gordon!